# How do I evaluate and fix "subscript out of bounds" error?

Tags: r, error-handling

When I run the code below I receive: "Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : subscript out of bounds"

Through a process of elimination I've narrowed the issue down to the step.prob function, but I can't seem to debug it further than that.

I've read the other questions regarding this error but haven't found the answers useful/I don't know how to alter the responses to fit my situation.

**Main question: How do I debug the subscript out of bounds error?**

```
        P<-30
step.max=125
s<-step.max
walkW <- function(n.times=125,
               xlim=c(524058,542800),
               ylim=c(2799758,2818500),
               start=c(542800,2815550),
               stepsize=c(4000,4000)) {
pic<-readImage("yourpic.png",all=TRUE,package="EBImage") #use whatever binary image you have on hand
 plot(c(0,0),type="n",xlim=xlim,ylim=ylim,
           xlab="Easting",ylab="Northing") 
    x <- start[1]
    y <- start[2]
    steps <- 1/c(1,2,4,8,12,16)
    steps.y <- c(steps,-steps,0)
    steps.x <- c(steps[c(1,5,6)],-steps,0)
    points(x,y,pch=16,col="green",cex=1)

for (i in 1:n.times) {
        repeat {
           xi <- stepsize[1]*sample(steps.x,1)
           yi <- stepsize[2]*sample(steps.y,1)
           newx <- x+xi
           newy <- y+yi
           if (newx>xlim[1] && newx<xlim[2] &&
               newy>ylim[1] && newy<ylim[2]) break
        }
        lines(c(x,newx),c(y,newy),col="white")
        x <- newx
        y <- newy

##The error is coming from the following function
step.prob<-function(n.times=step.max){
CS<-pic[x,y,1]
CS.max<-1
step.num<-15
SP<-(((CS/CS.max)*(1-(step.num/step.max))+(step.num/step.max))*100)
}
z<-step.prob(1)

##end of broken function

if(z>P)break
else

if(step.max){points(newx,newy,pch=16,col="yellow",cex=1)
}

 }
}
set.seed(101)
walkW(s)
```

Thanks in advance for all your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow I feel dumb now. The answer is simple! My arena is bound by statement

```
               xlim=c(524058,542800),
               ylim=c(2799758,2818500),
               start=c(542800,2815550),
               stepsize=c(4000,4000)) {
pic<-readImage("yourpic.png",all=TRUE,package="EBImage") #use whatever binary image you have on hand
 plot(c(0,0),type="n",xlim=xlim,ylim=ylim,
           xlab="Easting",ylab="Northing")
```

which represents the actual GPS coordinates in the referenced image, but the step.prob function was referencing pixel coordinates rather than arena coordinates.The issue came from the simple fact that my function was referencing the wrong scale.

To fix it I looked at the dimensions of the image I'm using with

```
dim(pic)
```

which told me the image was 648 * 615. 
Then I re-wrote the arena to be a perfect square on that scale instead:

```
           xlim=c(0,615),
           ylim=c(0,615),
           start=c(307,307)
```

Problem fixed!